# Getting all open compositions in After Effects Extend Script

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I want to write an After Effects script that process all currently open compositions.

I've found `app.project.activeItem`, but that gives me only the composition that's currently in the viewer, instead of all compositions that are open in the timeline.

I've also found `app.project.items` but that gives me all compositions (and other objects) and I can't find a way to check whether a composition in that list is actually open as a tab in the timeline.

Comment: I had a look, neither app, project or composition seems to have a property or method that would do this. Can't think of a workaround either. Make a feature request to Adobe

Comment: Thanks for checking! :) And pity it doesn't seem possible... A thought: does After Effects scripting have any window manipulation things? Maybe something to check what tabs are open in a subwindow or something like that? Since I essentially want to know what tabs of the timeline window are open and just knowing the name of the tab would be enough.

Comment: Do you have the after effects scripting guide? Not the best documentation, but it might help you out. https://blogs.adobe.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/48/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf

Comment: I had seen that one but had ignored it because it's 5 years old. However, I haven't found anything better so I actually should have a look, thanks for reminding me of this document! :) So far documentation for After Effects scripting is a pretty bad experience: there's no comprehensive API doc, Extend Script is only available in Creative Cloud if you enable showing older programs, etc. I ended up mostly figuring things out by using the Extend Script debugger and `.reflect.properties` and `.reflect.methods`, and by looking at how the Duik plugin does things.

Comment: Yeah, Adobe are really helping the developer community by keeping their documentation up to date, said no developer ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
function openComps() {
  var comps = [];
  do {
    comps.unshift(app.project.activeItem);
    app.executeCommand(app.findMenuCommandId("Close"));
  } while (app.project.activeItem != null && app.project.activeItem instanceof CompItem);

  for (var i = 0; i < comps.length; i++) {
    comps[i].openInViewer();
  }

  return comps
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).